# Rails: redirect_to :controller=>'tips', :action => 'show', :id => @tip.permalink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action

I tried to redirect rails to show action  by passing controller, action, and params.  However, rails ignores the name of action totally!

what I got is
http://mysite/controllername/paramId

so i have error message....

here is the action code I used:

```
def update
    @tip = current_user.tips.find(params[:id])
    @tip.attributes = params[:tip]
    @tip.category_ids = params[:categories]
    @tip.tag_with(params[:tags]) if params[:tags]


    if @tip.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Tip was successfully updated.'
      redirect_to :controller=>'tips', :action => 'show', :id => @tip.permalink
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This might be a temporary "get around".  Using render, it works very well....

```
if @tip.save
  flash[:notice] = 'Tip was successfully updated.'
   render :action => 'show', :id => @tip.permalink
 # redirect_to :controller=>'tips', :action => 'show', :id => @tip.permalink
else
  render :action => 'edit'
end
```

Answer (score 35):

Why fight the framework?

```
redirect_to @tip
```

And you can shorten your code by using the :notice option.

```
redirect_to @tip, :notice => 'Message here'
```

Comment: I did not know about the :notice shortcut on redirect_to. Thanks, that will certainly save a bit of time. Is there an equivalent for flash.now and render?

Answer (score 7):

If its a REST resource route, the routing is actually correct. A `GET` request on `/tips/id` actually calls the `show` action. Because of the way it is routing, my guess is that you routed it with `map.resources`, and this is correct.